# Why it is better to use DialogFragment for creating a dialog instead of an Activity class?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I am a beginner in android development. I am currently reading about Fragments from developer.android.com and this showed up about DialogFragment:

> DialogFragment
>       Displays a floating dialog. Using this class to create a dialog is a good alternative to using the dialog helper methods in the Activity
>   class, because you can incorporate a fragment dialog into the back
>   stack of fragments managed by the activity, allowing the user to
>   return to a dismissed fragment.

Can anybody explain this to me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is lightweight and easy to implement. You need to style your activity to display a dialog. First, you have to understand the difference between activity and fragment.

**Activity:**

> Activities have been around for a very long time and are used to
>   construct a single screen of your application. When someone is using
>   your Android application, the views that the user sees and interacts
>   with are hosted and controlled by a single activity. Much of your code
>   lives in these Activity classes, and there will typically be one
>   activity visible on the screen at a time.

**Fragment**

> Fragments are another type of controller class that allows us to
>   separate components of our applications into reusable pieces.
>   Fragments must be hosted by an activity and an activity can host one
>   or more fragments at a time. A simple fragment looks similar to an activity, but has different life
>   cycle callback methods.

One of the original goals of the fragment concept was to help developers make applications that provide different user experiences on phones and tablets.

The canonical example of fragment use is an email client. Let’s take a look at the Gmail app. When running on a phone, the Gmail app will display a list of the user’s emails. Tapping on one of these emails will transition the screen to showing the detail view for that particular email. This process is composed of two separate screens.

**For your Question:**

It is always better to use dialog fragment instead of Activity. Because fragments are more customizable and easy to use. Light weight and gives reusability.

You can know more here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2126865